# Mapping Class Inheritance Hierarchies Failed Mapping

Tags: inheritance, sqlalchemy, hierarchy

I have the following code:

```
class Entity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entity'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    entity_type = Column('type',Enum('asset','institution','model'))
    source_table_id = Column(Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'entity',
        'polymorphic_on':entity_type,
        }

class Asset(Entity):    
    __tablename__ = 'asset'

    id = Column('entity_id',Integer, ForeignKey('entity.id'), primary_key=True)
    asset_type = Column('type',Enum('listed','private'))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'asset',
        'polymorphic_on':asset_type,
        'with_polymorphic':'*'
        }

class Listed(Asset):
    __tablename__ = 'listed'

    id = Column('asset_entity_id',Integer, ForeignKey('asset.entity_id'), primary_key=True)
    ticker = Column('ticker',String)
    isin = Column('isin',String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'listed',
        }
```

I believe that if I query `Entity` I should get back a `Listed` object.

**Working sequence**

1. clear workspace
2. Performing a query on `Listed` yields a `Listed` object.
3. Performing a query on `Entity` yields a `Listed` object.

**Broken sequence**

1. clear workspace
2. Performing a query on `Entity` yields a `Asset` object.
3. Performing a query on `Listed` yields a `Asset` object.

**Console**

```
In [75]: reset

Once deleted, variables cannot be recovered. Proceed (y/[n])? y


In [76]: from fms import *

In [77]: import test

In [78]: listeds = session.query(test.Listed).filter(test.Listed.id == 2605).all()
    ...: l = listeds[0]
    ...: l.isin
Out[78]: 'ZAE000115184'

In [79]: entities = session.query(test.Entity).filter(test.Entity.id == 2605).all()
    ...: e = entities[0]
    ...: e.isin
Out[79]: 'ZAE000115184'

In [80]: reset

Once deleted, variables cannot be recovered. Proceed (y/[n])? y

In [81]: from fms import *

In [82]: import test

In [83]: entities = session.query(test.Entity).filter(test.Entity.id == 2605).all()
    ...: e = entities[0]
    ...: e.isin
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-78a0841e0935> in <module>()
      1 entities = session.query(test.Entity).filter(test.Entity.id == 2605).all()
      2 e = entities[0]
----> 3 e.isin

AttributeError: 'Asset' object has no attribute 'isin'

In [84]: listeds = session.query(test.Listed).filter(test.Listed.id == 2605).all()
    ...: l = listeds[0]
    ...: l.isin
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-537bcd7f1cb3> in <module>()
      1 listeds = session.query(test.Listed).filter(test.Listed.id == 2605).all()
      2 l = listeds[0]
----> 3 l.isin

AttributeError: 'Asset' object has no attribute 'isin'
```

Comment: This is a very-very tricky domain: multi-level inheritance definition within the same hierarchy. If you do not want to have unexpected behavior, I would get rid of `asset_type` and roll up to the `Entity` only..

Comment: Unfortunately for me this MySQL database exists along with a Matlab ORM suite mapping it along with business logic in Matlab. I am bound to use these tables and classes to satisfy the logic of the design. Its a pity as I thought SQLAlchemy would be able to handle this simple example. This honestly looks like a in SQLAlchemy.